# Can't get form data to node server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, post

I'm trying to get the data from a form to go to my local node server but it's not showing in the terminal.
I'm very new to all this so please forgive any noob mistakes.

Here's how I intend for this to flow:

When you fill out the HTML form and submit, the details of the form should show up in the server terminal.
I later intend to use this data to populate another html page, that's why I want to see it in terminal to know that the data is being received and processed correctly.
I hope this makes sense.

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Task Managing App</title>
  <style>
    /* Custom CSS */
    .input-field label {
      color: #9e9e9e !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #1f2631;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="margin-top: 2rem;" class="col s12 m10 offset-m1 l8 offset-l2 xl6 offset-xl3 section">
        <div class="card" style="border-radius: 12px;">
          <div class="card-content" >
            <span class="card-title">Task Managing App</span>
            <form id="task-form" action="http://localhost:3000/store-task" method="POST">
              <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" name="task" id="task" required>
                <label for="task">Task Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" name="category" id="category" required>
                <label for="category">Task Category <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field">
                <textarea name="description" id="description" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                <label for="description">Task Description</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" name="deadline" id="deadline" required>
                <label for="deadline">Deadline (DD/MM/YYYY) <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field">
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="reminder" id="reminder" />
                    <span style="color: #9e9e9e;">Reminder</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div id="reminder-options" style="display: none;">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <select name="frequency" id="frequency">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose frequency</option>
                      <option value="30mins">30 mins before</option>
                      <option value="1hour">1 hour before</option>
                      <option value="1day">1 day before</option>
                      <option value="3days">3 days before</option>
                      <option value="1week">1 week before</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="frequency">Reminder Frequency</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <select name="notification" id="notification">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose notification type</option>
                      <option value="email">Email</option>
                      <option value="notifications">Notifications</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="notification">Notification Type</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6 left-align">
                  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light red" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='homepage.html'">
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6 right-align">
                  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
                    Create Task
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery 3.5.1 uncompressed -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js code:

```
/** @format */
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Declaring, identifying and initializing UI Variables
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const inputTask = document.querySelector('#task');
const inputCategory = document.querySelector('#category');
const inputDescription = document.querySelector('#description');
const inputDeadline = document.querySelector('#deadline');
const reminderCheckbox = document.querySelector('#reminder');
const frequencySelect = document.querySelector('#frequency');
const notificationSelect = document.querySelector('#notification');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearTasks = document.querySelector('.clear-btn');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Load all event listeners
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
loadEventListener();

function loadEventListener() {
  // Loads stored tasks
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadTasks);
  //Add task event
  form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
  //Remove task
  taskList.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
  // Clear Task List
  clearTasks.addEventListener('click', clearTaskList);
  // Show/hide reminder options
  reminderCheckbox.addEventListener('change', toggleReminderOptions);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Functions
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Load tasks from local storage on page start
function loadTasks() {
  let tasks;
  if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
    tasks = [];
  } else {
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  }
  tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    createNewTaskElement(task);
  });
}

//Creates li & a-Tag element and adds it to the ul
function createNewTaskElement(task) {
  const newTask = document.createElement('li');
  newTask.className = 'collection-item';
  newTask.innerHTML = `
    <div>${task.task}</div>
    <div>${task.category}</div>
    <div>${task.description}</div>
    <div>${task.deadline}</div>
  `;
  const newTaskATag = document.createElement('a');
  newTaskATag.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  newTaskATag.style.color = '#e01a4f';
  newTaskATag.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
  newTaskATag.innerHTML = '<i class="material-icons">delete</i>';

  newTask.appendChild(newTaskATag);

  taskList.appendChild(newTask);
}

// Adds a new task to the Task List
function addTask(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

  // Retrieve form data from input fields
  const taskData = {
    task: inputTask.value,
    category: inputCategory.value,
    description: inputDescription.value,
    deadline: inputDeadline.value,
    reminder: reminderCheckbox.checked,
    frequency: frequencySelect.value,
    notification: notificationSelect.value
  };

  // Log the form data for debugging
  console.log(taskData);

  // Send the form data to the server
  fetch('/store-task', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(taskData)
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('Task added successfully');
      // Redirect to homepage or perform other actions as needed
    } else {
      throw new Error('Failed to add task'); // Throw an error if response is not ok
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error adding task:', error);
    // Handle the error here (e.g., display an error message to the user)
  });
}



// Saves task to local storage
function storeTaskInLocalStorage(task) {
  let tasks;
  if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {
    tasks = [];
  } else {
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  }

  tasks.push(task);

  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

// Deletes a single task from the task list
function deleteTask(e) {
  if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

      removeTaskFromLocalStorage(
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.firstChild.textContent
      );
    }
  }
}

// Delete task from local storage
function removeTaskFromLocalStorage(taskToDelete) {
  let tasks;
  tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
  tasks.forEach(function (task, index) {
    if (task.task === taskToDelete) {
      tasks.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

// Show/hide reminder options
function toggleReminderOptions() {
  const reminderOptions = document.getElementById('reminder-options');
  if (this.checked) {
    reminderOptions.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    reminderOptions.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

// Deletes all tasks from taskList
function clearTaskList() {
  while (taskList.firstChild) {
    taskList.removeChild(taskList.firstChild);
  }
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

My server.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const path = require('path'); // Import the path module

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());

// Serve the homepage.html file
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'homepage.html'));
});

// POST endpoint to store task data
app.post('/store-task', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const taskData = req.body;
        console.log('Received task data:', taskData);
  
        // Check if taskData is empty or null
        if (!taskData) {
          throw new Error('Invalid task data');
        }
  
        // Here, you can store the task data in a database or perform other actions
  
        // Send a success response
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error processing task data:', error);
        // Send an error response
        res.status(500).send('Internal server error');
    }
});


// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here's the response I'm getting in the terminal:

```
Server is running on port 3000
Received task data: {}
```

I even added the following to app.post in the server.js file

```
    const taskData = req.body;
    console.log('Received task data:', taskData);
    console.log('Received task data:');
    console.log('Task:', taskData.task);
    console.log('Category:', taskData.category);
    console.log('Description:', taskData.description);
    console.log('Deadline:', taskData.deadline);
    console.log('Reminder:', taskData.reminder);
    console.log('Frequency:', taskData.frequency);
    console.log('Notification:', taskData.notification);
```

But the response is:

```
Received task data: {}
Received task data:
Task: undefined
Category: undefined
Description: undefined
Deadline: undefined
Reminder: undefined
Frequency: undefined
Notification: undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace :

     body: JSON.stringify(taskData)

with 

 body: taskData

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the output in the terminal.

Comment: What is the result of "console.log(taskData)"?

Comment: @TheKNVB "console.log(taskData)" gives "{ }"

Comment: Press F12, and then click "console" tab, what error message(s) is/are prompted when you click on the "create task" button

Comment: i think you're missing bodyParser. try adding `app.use(express.bodyParser());`

Comment: @TheKNVB there are no errors showing...I get a 200 response.

Comment: are you including app.js in html..? I don't see it, it should be below jquery.. If not, then you're posting html form, which sends it as url-encoded request, not JSON..

Comment: @traynor When i include "<script src="app.js"></script>" below jquery, the form does not submit.

Comment: well, that's the problem, you were sending plain html form, and JSON parser cannot parse it.. (if you add `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))`, then you should get data). well, you need to debug it now, check errors in dev tools, it seems you're missing some html elements (collection)

Comment: @traynor I added this code to the server.js file and I'm getting some outputs in the terminal

Comment: yes, but you need to send the request from app.js, not html page. so, include app.js, and then debug the code. it seems you're missing collection html element, this fails here: `const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');` so, you need to add it or get it after it's added to the dom, i.e. you need to debug the code now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256887/discussion-between-gwin-and-traynor).

Comment: nothing more to add, voted for closing

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

Replace the following:

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Declaring, identifying and initializing UI Variables
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const inputTask = document.querySelector('#task');
const inputCategory = document.querySelector('#category');
const inputDescription = document.querySelector('#description');
const inputDeadline = document.querySelector('#deadline');
const reminderCheckbox = document.querySelector('#reminder');
const frequencySelect = document.querySelector('#frequency');
const notificationSelect = document.querySelector('#notification');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearTasks = document.querySelector('.clear-btn');

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Load all event listeners
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
loadEventListener();
```

with

```
let clearTasks,form,frequencySelect;
let inputCategory,inputDescription,inputDeadline,inputTask;
let notificationSelect,reminderCheckbox,taskList;

$( document ).ready(()=>{
    form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
    inputTask = document.querySelector('#task');
    inputCategory = document.querySelector('#category');
    inputDescription = document.querySelector('#description');
    inputDeadline = document.querySelector('#deadline');
    reminderCheckbox = document.querySelector('#reminder');
    frequencySelect = document.querySelector('#frequency');
    notificationSelect = document.querySelector('#notification');
    taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
    clearTasks = document.querySelector('.clear-btn');
    loadEventListener();
});
```

To make the document.querySelector function works, we need to wait for all DOM objects to be ready, so we need to have a "load" event handler for all variable initialization.

You may see my sample code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/74qwa1zu/).

Comment: Still getting the same undefined outputs

Comment: You can see my sample code, my solution can make the taskData variable contains values.

Comment: I see that it's working in the link you provided. 
But when I try to incorporate it into my code I get the same result. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing it wrong.
Could you possibly post the modified HTML and js files with your code in it?

Comment: the OP wasn't using the code, so this is just a red herring.. variables are referencing elements that exist on the DOM, so when the form is posted, it will contain current value, so there is no need to wait for load in this case

Comment: If the "console.log(taskData)" returns values, that is a server-side code problem, else that is a client-side problem.

Comment: Because of using jQuery, I update my code accordingly.